# Ошибка при загрузке ListView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

Учусь работать с DrawerLayout.
При запуске приложения возникает следующая ошибка

```
Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
```

Все фрагменты у меня фактически схожи, отличаются лишь загружаемыми массивами, поэтому приведу лишь один пример

Фрагмент

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;



public class PastaFragment extends ListFragment {


public PastaFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pasta));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pasta, container, false);
}

}
```

Макет фрагмента

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.hfad.bitsandpizzas.PastaFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Вывод

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.hfad.bitsandpizzas, PID: 1965
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
                                                 at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:402)
                                                 at android.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:203)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:904)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
                                                 at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
                                                 at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Обращение к списку в активности

```
drawerList = findViewById(R.id.drawer);
drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Список в макете активности

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#ffffff">
    </ListView>
```

Возможно ещё следует упомянуть что при клике на элемент списка должен загружаться ListFragment. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: В приведенном коде нет упоминания R.id.list - найдите его, возможно он гдето в фрагменте упоминается.

Comment: Использую в MainActivity ListView   private ListView drawerList;  drawerList = findViewById(R.id.drawer);

Comment: а где вы используете андроидный ресурс `android.R.id.list`? в какой строчке вообще ошибка покажите

Comment: В этом то и проблема, в логе нет указания на строку. Я сейчас выложу полный вывод

Comment: Коды активности в вопросе смените на коды фрагмента - ошибка явно происходит в нём - похоже в его разметке этот `id` задан не в том тэге

Comment: добавил пример кода фрагментов

Comment: для решения вашего вопроса в нем явно не хватает части кода. Откуда вообще этот id `android.R.id.list`? Посмотрите внимательно код

Comment: я добавил фрагмент кода, где обращаюсь к списку

Comment: Вы точно показали тот фрагмент на котором падает? Разметка тоже та? С этой разметкой он должен вылетать с другой ошибкой - об отсутствии в ней `ListView` вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему заменой метода onCreateView фрагментов на метод onActivityCreated, и стёр упоминания о макете

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pasta));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```